# Google Cloud Engine. Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: google-compute-engine

I can not connect via ssh any more,
I was be able to connect for almost 24 hours.
All of a sudden, `ssh` stops working.
I had many users and I also added a new (tomcat) user in that VM.

I am get the below message when I try to ssh to my instance:

```
"Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)."
```

I ended up removing ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine*

Removed the 'sshKeys' metadata from Cloud Engine Console

Tried `gcutil ssh` again, this created new  `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine` file as well as `sshKeys metadata`.

But still I am getting that error.

Comment: I ended it up creating a different user on the instance using  **--ssh_user=anotheruser** flag in gcutil, and this worked.

Comment: you should stop using google cloud. It's a forever alpha/beta product. Always broken with broken and bloated SDKs

Comment: why doesn't Google tell us this? Or have instruction that worked?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I was debugging it for about 16 hours. Yet that I have found the solution I'd like you to have a share in my odyssey.

I was running GitLab on Google Compute Engine advertised as one click installation.

Well, finally as I tried to clone a private repository, I got the error message:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

I looked after the **private/public key pair** and I found nothing unusual.

---

Then I thought there might something wrong with the **sshd** on the server as I got the debug message:

```
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
[...]
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
```

So I checked a plethora of different **sshd** settings but nothing really fixed the issue.

---

And at last I started debugging on the server side and found the error:

```
sshd[7364]: debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys': Permission denied
```

Finally this was the highway to happiness. Because the file existed and **sshd** knew which file it has to load. However, somehow there was a **permission issue**.

So I checked if the **chmod** of the files in the **remote** `.ssh` folder were ok. I found nothing unusual.

---

And here is the solution:

**SELinux** did have a problem with the location of the `.ssh` folder and was not willing to give permission to the **ssh daemon**.
By either executing the command

`restorecon -Rv /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/`

or

`semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

One of both commands solved the issue. I'll be glad if someone could verify which of those both!

So you don't need to deactivate **SELinux**!

Comment: Wow, you're a lifesaver. I ran the following commands to get GitLab working:

    `sudo yum -y install policycoreutils-python &&
    sudo semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

You answered my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427165/git-push-pull-fails-on-gitlab-in-google-compute-engine/26533826#26533826

Comment: For me, on a Google Compute Engine instance, I was trying to connect like root, which is disabled by default. Simply just trying to ssh with my username works flawlessly. Thanks anyway! More info here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-advanced#root

Answer (score 5):

This is really a comment on the correct solution by **@sxleixer**, but I wanted formatting.

1. The `semanage` tool is not installed by default. Go get it with

   ```
   sudo yum -y install policycoreutils-python
   ```
2. Allow the nonstandard ssh_home_t

   ```
   sudo semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys"
   ```
3. Either restart `sshd` or do a full restart with

   ```
   sudo shutdown -r now
   ```
4. Test everything is working locally

   ```
   ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "test@example.com"
   cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub # Copy-paste the key to the 'My SSH Keys' section under the 'SSH' tab in your user profile
   ssh -T git@localhost  # Should now output "Welcome to GitLab"
   ```

This fixes the one click installation of GitLab on Google Compute Engine.

There is indeed no good reason to turn off SELinux.

Comment: Thanks for formatting and clearly defining the process. You helped answer my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427165/git-push-pull-fails-on-gitlab-in-google-compute-engine/26533826#26533826

Answer (score 3):

In this situation, it's likely the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file for your primary user is misconfigured. It's possible that the file has the wrong data in it, but I suspect you actually need to fix the permissions.  Try this:

```
gcutil ssh --ssh_user=anotheruser <yourinstance>
sudo su - <youruser>
chmod 700 .ssh
chmod 600 .ssh/authorized_keys
```

And then try logging in as your user again.

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

1. change the you private key permission to 0600 on instance 1
2. `ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa user2@instance-2`

Answer (score 1):

In my case i had to generated ssh keys using gcloud compute ssh and copy all files from ~/.ssh to the remote machine and it worked.

files genetarion:

```
gcloud init
gcloud compute ssh --zone "zone" "vm_name"  --project "project_name"
exit
```

files copy:

```
scp -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine ~/.ssh/* <user>@<IP>:~/.ssh
```

permissions and files check:

```
-rw-------. 1 your_user your_user 1161 Apr  7 07:50 /home/your_user/.ssh/authorized_keys
-rw-------. 1 your_user your_user 1679 Apr  7 07:52 /home/your_user/.ssh/google_compute_engine
-rw-r--r--. 1 your_user your_user  399 Apr  7 07:52 /home/your_user/.ssh/google_compute_engine.pub
-rw-r--r--. 1 your_user your_user  189 Apr  7 07:52 /home/your_user/.ssh/google_compute_known_hosts
-rw-r--r--. 1 your_user your_user  444 Apr  7 07:52 /home/your_user/.ssh/known_hosts
```

test connection :

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/google_compute_engine <IP>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything above, and am still getting this error message.

This is with a new CentOS 8 VM.  I have no problems with a CentOS 7 VM, it just works, and keeps on working, but the problem seems to be with CentOS 8.

I provided full information & logs here (this may be a different issue than here, but it's the same error message):

`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58430955/ssh-stops-working-on-centos-8-gce-vm-permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex`

Something is really wrong here with GCE, it looks like this has been happening on/off over the last 5+ years, this page has over 13K views.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this, i encountered the same problem and the below solution worked fine.
Edit the "/etc/ssh/sshd_config" file on your system using vi/vim or any other editor and set "PasswordAuthentication" to yes

Answer (score -1):

Turn off selinux.

```
setenforce 0
```

Also set SELINUX to permissive in /etc/selinux/config.

Then go upvote this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24212432/162070