# Git push/pull fails on GitLab in Google Compute Engine

Tags: gitlab, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I've installed GitLab on Google Compute Engine using "Click to Deploy" from the project interface. The deployment is successful after a few minutes. I can SSH into the instance, and muck around with it as expected.

I can also log in to GitLab using the web interface, and add SSH keys to my profile. So far, so good. However, when I attempt to push or pull to a new example repository, I receive this message:

```
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I've removed my local SSH config so it doesn't interfere. Do I need to setup an SSH tunnel of some sort? What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** Wiping out my local ~/.ssh folder, and regenerating an SSH key (which I've added to my profile in GitLab) produces the following error:

```
Received disconnect from {GITLAB_IP_ADDRESS}: 2: Too many authentication failures for git
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

**UPDATE 2:** It seems GitLab may already have a solution: run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. See here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#git-ssh-access-stops-working-on-selinux-enabled-systems

Comment: Have you run `ssh-keygen -t rsa`, and copied `id_rsa.pub` into your GitLab profile? Then added yourself to the project with the correct access to pull down/push up code?

Comment: Yep. I've actually regenerated the SSH key, and wiped out my local ~/.ssh folder to be sure.

Comment: When you are pulling/pushing, what password are you entering? The one you created with the key, or your server user password?

Comment: It never even asks for a password, regardless of whether I use a key that has one or not.

Comment: Wipe the host from your `known_hosts` file, and try again?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create an SSH tunnel to communicate with GitLab.

#### 1. Log into your development server as your user, and create a key.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Follow the steps, and create a passcode (that you can remember) as you'd need this to pull and push code from/to GitLab.

#### 2. Now that you've created your key, we can copy it;

```
cat id_rsa.pub
```

Copy the output of that command (including `ssh-rsa`), and add it to your GitLab profile. (http://my-gitlab-server.com/profile/keys/new).

#### 3. Ensure you have the correct privilege to the project(s)

Ensure you are at role developer at the very least. (Screengrab of roles: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSSvl.jpg)

#### 4. Now, copy the project link

Go into your project, and find the SSH link in the top right;

[image]

#### 5. Now back to your development server

Navigate to your directory where you'd like to work, and run the following;

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin <<project_url>>
$ git fetch
```

*Where `<<project_url>>` is the link we copied in step 4.*

You will be prompted your password (this is your ssh key password, not your server password) and to add the host to your `known_hosts` file. After that, the project will start to download and you can enjoy development.

I did these steps on a CentOS 6.4 machine with Digital Ocean. But they shouldn't differ from using Google CE.

#### Edit

*Quote from [Marty Penner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1882911/marty-penner) answer as per [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26427165/git-push-pull-fails-on-gitlab-in-google-compute-engine/26427400#comment41693874_26427400)*

Solved it! Thanks to @sxleixer and @Alexander Wenzowski for figuring this out.

Apparently, SELinux was interfering with a non-standard location for the .ssh directory. I needed to run the following commands on the Compute Engine instance:

```
sudo yum -y install policycoreutils-python # Install the `semanage` tool
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys" # Allow the nonstandard ssh_home_t
```

See the full thread here:

[Google Cloud Engine. Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440096/google-cloud-engine-permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic/26365704#26365704)

Comment: I followed all of the steps from scratch. I'm still getting the second error in my question ("Too many authentication failures").

Comment: Hmm. Perhaps there is a cooldown period and you've been blacklisted for a short while due to previous attempts?

Comment: Good question. I don't know of any such cooldown period, but maybe leaving it for a day is in order.

Comment: I've not used Google CE before, but could you not just destroy the current instance and rebuild? (assuming no projects are on the current build) - it would mean we wouldn't have to wait

Comment: Done. Still the same issue. Bizarre.

Comment: Weird. If you like, you can add me on Skype (purely for IM'ing) and I can try and help you out further tonight? (Skype: harry.sniko)

Comment: You're awesome. That would be great, but unfortunately, I'm gone for the weekend, leaving this afternoon with limited bandwidth. If this doesn't get answered by Monday, are you OK with chatting sometime then?

Comment: Absolutely, no problem! I may even get time to deploy another GitLab server tonight using Google CE (if I do, I'll document and update my answer)

Comment: Thanks for all your help. You clearly defined the process. If you add the commands from my answer below, I'll flag your answer as correct and complete.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it! Thanks to [@sxleixer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3197723/sxleixer) and [@Alexander Wenzowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/902839/alexander-wenzowski) for figuring this out.

Apparently, SELinux was interfering with a non-standard location for the .ssh directory. I needed to run the following commands on the Compute Engine instance:

```
sudo yum -y install policycoreutils-python # Install the `semanage` tool
sudo semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t "/var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys" # Allow the nonstandard ssh_home_t
```

See the full thread here:

[Google Cloud Engine. Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440096/google-cloud-engine-permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic/26365704#26365704)

**UPDATE:** It seems GitLab may already have a solution: run `sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure`. See here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/blob/master/README.md#git-ssh-access-stops-working-on-selinux-enabled-systems

Comment: Awesome! Glad you could fix it. Apologies, I didn't manage to get time to experiment

Answer (score 0):

In my situation the git user wasn´t set up completely. If you get in your log files messages like "User git not allowed because account is locked" (Under Centos or Redhat it´s /var/log/secure) than you simply need to activate the user via "passwd -d git"