# Gitlab - Too many authentication failures for git

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

My command line git is not working since last week, all I remember is that I init a local folder into git version controlled, and add a remote git ref to it. Then my git is unable to push or pull. It shows:

```
git clone git@gitlab.xxx.com:xxx/myproj.git myproj
Cloning into 'myproj'...
Received disconnect from 192.168.xxx.xxx: 2: Too many authentication failures for git
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

What's weird is that my version control in JetBrain Idea works fine, it can still pull or push that project which can't be pull in command line.

I've add the id_rsa.pub to gitlab before, and I re-add it again now, but it does not work.

My ssh debug info

ssh -v git@gitlab.xxx.com

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.xxx.com [192.168.xxx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/abc/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/abc/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA d7:11:d8:62:a6:30:1d:4a:c7:f1:99:bd:ba:54:de:60
debug1: Host 'gitlab.corp.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/abc/.ssh/known_hosts:127
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.cn0
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.cn6
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.cn1
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.cn2
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.cn5
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.cn8
Received disconnect from 192.168.100.218: 2: Too many authentication failures for git
abc@LiuzhMacbook:~/.ssh$
abc@LiuzhMacbook:~/.ssh$ ls
authorized_keys  id_rsa           known_hosts      tmp/
abc@LiuzhMacbook:~/.ssh$ rm known_hosts
abc@LiuzhMacbook:~/.ssh$ ssh -v git@gitlab.corp.com
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.corp.com [192.168.100.218] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/abc/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/abc/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH_5*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA d7:11:d8:62:a6:30:1d:4a:c7:f1:99:bd:ba:54:de:60
The authenticity of host 'gitlab.corp.com (192.168.100.218)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is d7:11:d8:62:a6:30:1d:4a:c7:f1:99:bd:ba:54:de:60.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.corp.com,192.168.100.218' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.cn0
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.cn6
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.cn1
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.cn2
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.cn5
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,hostbased
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/abc/.ssh/id_rsa.cn8
Received disconnect from 192.168.100.218: 2: Too many authentication failures for git
```

Comment: Maybe intellij is not using using the same key as your %HOME%\.ssh? Try http://stackoverflow.com/a/26427400/6309

Comment: @VonC thanks, I just don't want to recreate my rsa cert, because I've use it every where, such as the login ssh verification of my production server

Comment: You can create as many key as you want, with a different name.

Comment: @VonC em. I've recreate my key, still not work

Comment: `ssh -vvv git@gitlab.xxx.com verify`. You probably offer too much keys from somewhere.

Comment: @VonC I think you are right . I update the debug info in my post. And after I kill the ssh process. It works fine. But what I worry about it's that when I use all the private keys, it will become not work again.

Comment: @Alexis What do you mean "use all the private keys"?

Comment: @Alexis I see: ssh by default proposes all the keys in `~/.ssh`. But you can limit your test to only one key: `ssh -Tv -i /path/to/my/private.key git@gitlab.xxx.com`

Comment: @VonC I mean if i use cn1's key, then use cn2's key ... till cn8. Then I ssh git@gitlab.xxx.com it will first offering cn1's key, then cn2's key ... At last failed with Too many authentication failures for git. And yes you are right, I should specify the private key

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a different ssh url in order to reference the right public/private key you want.
Add in your HOME/.ssh a file named config:

```
Host            mygitlab
Hostname        gitlab.xxx.com
User            git
IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/id_rsa.gitlab
IdentitiesOnly yes
```

And change your url:

```
git clone mygitlab:xxx/myproj.git myproj
```

That way, you avoid the default ssh behavior which presents every keys for ssh to try.

Answer (score 12):

[image]

In `SourceTree`, try changing `SSH Client` from `PuTTY/Plink` to `Open SSH`.

Comment: I switched to using SSH key, and it worked fine.  Switching to a new Plink key didn't work...

Answer (score 7):

First of all set your ssh keys.

If our keys are set correctly - try to restart the ssh-agent

```
eval $(ssh-agent)
```

You should see the PID of the process and you r keys will load.

To add your keys manually use: `ssh-add`. This will load the keys from you default `.ssh` folder

Comment: The ssh-add was a key step i missed. Thank You

Answer (score 2):

running on linux 
the following worked for me (I use gitlab):

```
  eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  ssh-add ~/.ssh/<ssh_directory>
  ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

and in one command:

```
 eval $(ssh-agent -s) &&  ssh-add ~/.ssh/gitlab &&   ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

Answer (score 2):

this maybe a **ssh** connect problem

when you delete a private key locally

you do not delete its **fingerprints of identitie**

use this command to check out

```
ssh-add -l
```

for more help

```
ssh-add -h
```

use this command to delete all identities

```
ssh-add -D
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this commands, actually save my day!!

Answer (score 0):

finally - primitive reboot of the host machine works, but would like to know what really happens...

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was I had a lot of old keys in .ssh folder. So, just removed them and everything worked properly.