# gcp ssh connection without password from localhost to localhost failed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to enable ssh connection without the password from localhost to localhost in google engine vm ( CentOS 7 )

I create the keys and add public to authorized_keys file
The file permission is ok ( other and group doesn't have wx )

But when I try to do connection it's failed

```
   ssh localhost

   Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

How to fix?

Comment: This might have been already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20440096/google-cloud-engine-permission-denied-publickey-gssapi-keyex-gssapi-with-mic

Comment: I see it, but it does not help.

Comment: Maybe try this in the directory  /etc/ssh/sshd_config turn the 'PasswordAuthentication' to 'yes' then re-start the service

Comment: also not working

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that in /etc/ssh/sshd_config file the root login was disable

```
PermitRootLogin no
```

I change it to

```
PermitRootLogin yes
```

And now I able to do ssh connection without the password.

Thank @Joe A I tried your solution and then discover the above line :)

Comment: glad I could help!!